# Matrix - how to create matrix from user input(rows)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create matrix from user input like this:

[image]

this is my code:

```
    flag = True
    while flag:
        num = int(input('enter matrix dimension:'))
        if num == 0:
            print('Finish')
            flag = False
        else:
            matrix = []
            for row in range(num):
                matrix.append([])
                for column in range(1):
                    value = eval(input('Enter elements in row with commas:'))
                    matrix[row].append(value)
            print (matrix)
            for row in range(len(matrix)):
                for column in range(len(matrix[row])):
                    print(matrix[row][column], end=" ")
                    print()
main()
```

the problem is that the type is tuple(I don't know why), and in the eval(input()) I can't put more arguments like num,row.
how can I fix this?

Comment: Why are you using `eval(input(...))` anyway?

Comment: i want the user to enter the matrix row in one line

Comment: Using `eval(input(...))` makes your code vulnerable as user input get's partially executed. Why should one be able to enter `print("hello")` for example? As you only enter comma separated values, why don't you do `value = input("enter ...:").split(",")` which results in a list holding your entered values?

Answer (score 0):

As I played around a little with `eval()`, I want to elaborate on this a little more and explain to the OP and possible readers, why using `eval()` with user input is dangerous.

---

Eval let's you run expressions in form of strings, like "1+1" or code objects created with the builtin function `compile()`.

**Example:**

```py
>>> expression = "1+1"
>>> res = eval(expression)
>>> print(res)
2
>>> compiled_expression = compile(expression, "<string>", "eval")
>>> print(compiled_expression.co_code)
b'd\x00S\x00'
>>> res = eval(compiled_expression)
>>> print(res)
2
```

The expression can be everything, which has a return value.

```py
>>> type(1+1)
<class 'int'>

>>> x = 42
>>> type(1 if x%2 == 0 else 1)
<class 'int'>

>>> type(print("Hi"))
Hi
<class 'NoneType'>

>>> type(import os)
  File "<bpython-input-42>", line 1
    type(import os)
         ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

We're getting this syntax error, because the expression `import os` has no return value. This means, we cannot import modules, but we can use all existing variables, constants, methods, classes and imported modules to craft an expression and call this expression via `eval(...)`.

From an attackers perspective, executing arbitrary code is kinda interesting. Consider of using the above code in a backend of a server, where user input from the frontend will be thrown into the builtin `eval()` method to fill a matrix, which is then returned to the frontend. Could be a valid scenario if one creates an online matrix calculator or stuff like that.

The code, if not open-sourced, is a blind spot for the attacker. If modules like `os`, `requests` or `subprocess` are already imported in your application, he's lucky. If not, there isn't much an attacker can do.

**How to trick `eval()`**:

You may have mentioned, that we can indeed call methods which have no return value at first glance. `print(...)` does not only print text to your screen, but also it returns something of type `<class 'NoneType'>`.
Given that, we can also run another very interesting builtin method: `exec()`.

Exec is a little like `eval()`, but kind of much more powerful and thus more dangerous. With `exec()`, we can as well run code in form of strings or compiled code objects like in the example above. But in contrast to `eval()`, we do not have to run a statement with a return value. With `eval()`, we can only run expressions which we can assign to some sort of variable.
With `exec()`, we can run any expression we want, independent of whether it has a return value or not. And moreover, the result of the expression stays permanent in the current process.

**Example**:

```py
>>> print(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    print(x)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
>>> exec("x = 1 + 1")
>>> print(x)
2
```

Let's do the check, if `exec(...)` is a valid expression, which has a return value or not and whether we can run it from `eval()`.

```py
>>> type(exec("x = 1 + 1"))
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Indeed, we can. With this little trick, we can now also run non-returning expressions from within `eval()`, like importing modules ...

Exploiting such arbitrary code execution vulnerabilities can have many impacts. The more or less harmless one is to simply crash the application because the input was not satisfied correctly. In terms of the mentioned matrix-calculator example, a row like `posix.uname_result(sysname='Linux', nodename='redacted', release='5.10.105-1-MANJARO', version='#1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Mar 11 14:12:33 UTC 2022', machine='x86_64')` would not make much sense.

Using `requests`, an attacker could also send data out before the script crashes. Or he could change files on the system, install a backdoor and so on.

**Exploitation**:

A successful exploitation could look like this:
[image: Exploitation of eval() using exec()]

(1) the attacker starts a listener on the attacking server.

(2) the attacker opens your online calculator (or in this case, the OP's script)

(3) the attacker inserts data

(4) when the attacker comes to the input, where `eval()` is used in the background, the code for spawning a reverse shell will be inserted like this: `exec("""start_reverse_shell(ip=<attackers ip>, port=<attacker port>)""")` (Note: `start_reverse_shell()` is not valid code, but I don't wanna post code for a reverse shell here ;) )
The script is now running the code, and as the provided statement has a return value, the current action is valid. The code for the reverse shell imports some modules and establishes a connection to the server of the attacker.

(5) The attacker has now access to the exploited server (as you can see from the output of "hostname" and "pwd").

**PS**
Please do NOT misuse possible vulnerabilities like this. Go for responsible disclosure and be happy about being such a good human being :)